# Any Double Click Event of nodes and text labels in Syncfusion Diagram?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, syncfusion

I'm developing a workflow system in which I have to open different types of forms on double click of text labels or bitmap nodes.

Can you please suggest relevant controls with such functionality or guide me if *Syncfusion* provides such functionality in diagram control ?

If they provide how can I use that?

Answer (score 1):

`Syncfusion` provides the support to achieve your requirement. We suggest you to use `diagram.EventSink`’s `“NodeDoubleClick”` Event to hook the Node Double Click event.

Please refer the below code for better understanding.

[C#]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //To Disable the Label editor of the Nodes
            diagram1.Controller.InPlaceEditing = false;

            TextNode txt = new TextNode("Syncfusion", new RectangleF(100, 100, 100, 70));
            diagram1.Model.AppendChild(txt);

            BitmapNode bitmp = new BitmapNode("../../sync.JPG");
            diagram1.Model.AppendChild(bitmp);

            //To hook the Node Double click event
            diagram1.EventSink.NodeDoubleClick += EventSink_NodeDoubleClick;

        }

        void EventSink_NodeDoubleClick(NodeMouseEventArgs evtArgs)
        {
            if(evtArgs.Node is BitmapNode || evtArgs.Node is TextNode)
            {
                //Write Logics to open new forms
            }
        }
```